# SSRS - Single page per row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

Creating a report that is a display of a persons online application, so there are text boxes and multiple tables per person.  I need each person to print on the same page, so a user can select either a particular application, or a date range, like all applications  for today and yesterday.  I currently have everything in a LIST object with a page break set on it, however the tables in the LIST would throw the "detail member with inner members" error.  I found a a way around that using the solution here: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/reporting-services-error-the-tablix/ , which got rid of the error, but any multiple row tables return a new row per page, so a person with 3 aliases, will have a 3 page report.  So, I am looking for a new tutorial on how to keep everything on one page, but allow my tables to return all results on the same page.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are writing the query out or using a stored procedure. If you are using a stored procedure if would make it a lot easier to use SSRS. But to get the grouping correct find a common record between the user and the aliases. Then be sure to pull that common identifier into the stored procedure. Then use the table wizard and pull in all the information you want to see and pull the common identifier into the row group box and it will format for you and group that person on the common identifier and hopefully give you the results you are looking for.